# Can I use `va_list` twice as following:

Tags: c

Can I use `va_list` as following:

```
void myself_printf(char* key, char* value, ...) {
    char real_key[1024];
    char real_value[1024];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, value);

    // use args twice format key and value
    vsnprintf(real_key, 1024000, key, args);
    vsnprintf(real_value, 1024000, value, args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

using in demo

```
myself_printf("%d-%s", "%s-%d", 12, "key", "value", 24);
expect: real_key is "12-key", and real_value is "value-24"
```

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about c++?

Comment: Well apparently you can. https://ideone.com/AlOoJ8

Comment: However, and that is unrelated to the question, allocating those large buffers on stack is bond to cause problems. Stack size is like 1MB by default on most compilers, and you're requiring 2MB from it to allocate `real_value` and `real_key`. Invoking this function might cause a crash. You have to either make those buffers smaller or allocate them on the heap using `malloc()`.

Comment: @havenard Incorrect

Comment: Not incorrect, just not complete. The 1MB default stack size is correct for VS2017, but not for Linux - `ulimit -s`.

Comment: Your code is bad: you are computing twice the same string (in two different buffers). Why can't you compute it once (with *one* call to `vsnprintf` only) then copy it (with `strcpy`) or simply reuse the same buffer twice.

Comment: The `1024000` is wrong, should be replaced by `sizeof(real_key)` in its first occurrence

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking, you must use `va_copy`, since `vsnprintf` can invalidate `args`.

```
void myself_printf(char* key, char* value, ...) {
    char real_key[1024000];
    char real_value[1024000];
    va_list args, args2;
    va_start(args, value);
    va_copy(args2, args);

    // use args twice format key and value
    vsnprintf(real_key, 1024000, key, args);
    vsnprintf(real_value, 1024000, value, args2);

    va_end(args);
    va_end(args2);
}
```

This is what `va_copy` is designed for.

As noted, this is a large amount of stack space, although it is within typical stack sizes. Consider using `vasprintf`, if it is available.

### Citations

n1548 §7.16

> The object ap may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate…

In other words, you cannot portably use `args` after you pass it to `vsnprintf`.

This is clarified in footnote 281:

> As the functions vfprintf, vfscanf, vprintf, vscanf, vsnprintf, vsprintf, and vsscanf invoke the va_arg macro, the value of arg after the return is indeterminate.

While it seems that `va_list` is passed by value, that does not mean that it is actually passed by value, or that the `va_list` itself encapsulates all of its state. A common trick with typedefs in C is to declare them as a 1-element array:

```
typedef int my_type[1];
```

Since `my_type` decays to pointer type when it is passed by function, it only *appears* to be passed by value.

### Demo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void func(const char *msg, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, msg);
    vfprintf(stdout, msg, ap);
    vfprintf(stdout, msg, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    func("%d + %d = %d\n", 2, 3, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, the output is:

```
2 + 3 = 5
590862432 + -1635853408 = 1586038440
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so (but could be wrong). OP is *using* the `args` value twice, and AFAIK passing it to `vsnprintf`  is not invalidatring the `args` value. But I could be wrong. The example for [`va_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_copy) is not similar to your code. When calling `vsnprintf`, `args` is passed by value.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, quite sure. Added citation.

Comment: But then won't it be the role of `vsnprintf` *implementation* to call `va_copy` (not of the code using it) ? It is not specified that `vsnprintf` is using `va_arg`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: What makes you think that `vsprintf` calls `va_copy`?

Comment: What make you think that `vsnprintf` is using `va_arg` (that is *not* in the specification)? It could use something else (an implementation specific trick)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It doesn’t matter whether `vsnprintf` *could* use something else, because as a matter of actual fact, common implementations *do* call `va_arg` and do not call `va_copy`.

Comment: Common implementations are *implementing* the specification of `vsnprintf`. It is not told how they do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190415/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Comment: Tjhe C11 standard says "if that function invokes the va_arg" but it does not say that `vsnprintf` is using `va_arg`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You are just repeating comments that you made in chat.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Please try out the example code. On my system (x86-64 Linux ELF), the output of the second vfprintf call is garbage.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This demonstrates that `va_list` is either not passed by value, or does not encapsulate its state.

Comment: I upvoted that answer, once the demo has been added into it

Comment: Very frustrating. Since it's quite a common scenario: call `vsnprintf`, check if the buffer is large enough and call it the second time with a larger buffer if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to using `va_copy()` — as suggested by [Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82294/dietrich-epp) in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274498) — you can simply use `va_start()` and `va_end()` twice.

```
void myself_printf(char *key_fmt, char *value_fmt, ...)
{
    char real_key[1024];
    char real_value[1024];
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, value);
    vsnprintf(real_key, sizeof(real_key), key_fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    vs_start(args, value);
    vsnprintf(real_value, sizeof(real_key), value_fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    …do something useful with real_key and real_value…
}
```

The original version of the question used `char real_key[1024000];` and similarly for `real_value`. Allocating almost 2 MiB of data on the stack won't work reliably on Windows (the limit there is usually 1 MiB of stack), and uses an awful lot of space on Unix systems (where the stack size is usually 8 MiB).  Be cautious!

You would need to use `va_copy()` if the `va_list` was passed as an argument to your function.  For example:

```
void myself_printf(char* key, char* value, ...)
{
    va_list args;    
    va_start(args, value);
    myself_vprintf(key, value, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void myself_vprintf(char *key_fmt, char *value_fmt, va_list args1)
{
    char real_key[1024];
    char real_value[1024];
    va_list args2;
    va_copy(args2, args1);

    vsnprintf(real_key, sizeof(real_key), key_fmt, args1);
    vsnprintf(real_value, sizeof(real_value), value_fmt, args2);
    va_end(args2);

    …do something useful with real_key and real_value…
}
```

The specification of [`va_end()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.3) says:

> The `va_end` macro facilitates a normal return from the function whose variable argument list was referred to by the expansion of the `va_start` macro, or the function containing the expansion of the `va_copy` macro, that initialized the `va_list ap`. The `va_end` macro may modify `ap` so that it is no longer usable (without being reinitialized by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro). If there is no corresponding invocation of the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro, or if the `va_end` macro is not invoked before the return, the behavior is undefined.

Note that the specification of the [`vfprintf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.8) function includes footnote [288](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note288) which says:

> As the functions `vfprintf`, `vfscanf`, `vprintf`, `vscanf`, `vsnprintf`, `vsprintf`, and `vsscanf` invoke the `va_arg` macro, the value of `arg` after the return is indeterminate.

Granted, footnotes are not normative, but this is a strong indication that the functions are expected to use `va_arg` and hence the double use of `arg` as shown in the question leads to undefined behaviour unless there is an intervening call to `va_end` and another `va_start` or a use of `va_copy` (and its matching `va_end`).

Comment: Recent link for [VS2017 /F (Set Stack Size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2017) and for Linux, `ulimit -s`. Both dead on.